# Firebase Database Unity can't set playerpref float with the value I read from the Database

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I need to read the coins value from the database and save it with playerprefs, the problem is, even tho the reading works and the first print() prints out the correct value read from the database, the value still wont save with playerprefs and it shows no errors. I tried doing this in many ways which technically do the same thing as the code I posted here but none works and they all seem to get stuck on the playerprefs save part.

UPDATE/EDIT: I tested, and it seems that the reading works with every type of variable except int and float, string works without a problem. This is still really weird to me.

**SOLVED:**
So this is probably a stupid way to do this, but its the only way i could. Instead of saving the number as an int in the database, i save it as a string and when i read the string from the database i parse it into a number, and then save that number with the playerprefs. This is a really weird bug and weird way i solved it lol

```
await databaseReference.Child(FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser.UserId.ToString()).Child("rockets").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith((load =>
            {
                if (load.IsCanceled)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else if (load.IsFaulted)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    DataSnapshot coins = load.Result;
                    print(coins.Value);
                    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("coins", (int)coins.Value);
                    PlayerPrefs.Save();
                    print("COINS SET: " + coins.Value);
                }
            }));
```

Comment: It's hard to be certain, but my guess is that you're not dealing with the asynchronous nature of the calls to the database. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48585136/how-to-use-async-in-unity-with-firebase or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57541573/unity-functions-called-inside-task-iscompleted-stop-program-from-continuing for some examples.

Comment: Hey! I've tried this fix now and it doesn't seem to fix the problem, still the same thing. The first print logs the value, but the print after the playerprefs save is supposed to happen doesnt happen, which indicates that the program gets stuck on the playerprefs save part. Still no errors

Comment: Both `print` calls print the same variable don't they? It's very unexpected if both of the print a different value. Can you edit your question to also include the output that your get from those print statements?

Comment: the second print call doesnt print at all, that is the problem. The program gets stuck on `PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("coins", (int)coins.Value);`

Answer (score 0):

After you set values in playerprefs, you have to also call PlayerPrefs.Save() to committ those values.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, but this still doesn't seem to fix the core problem which is that the writing to the playerprefs doesnt work, and it gets stuck on that line.

Comment: Are you in the main thread or a secondary one?  You can never call any Unity functions on secondary threads.  Usually it throws an exception when you do this, but sometimes it just fails.

Comment: Im really not sure what you mean by this, but this script is just like any other one of mine that playerprefs works in, so I guess it should be main?

Comment: The nature of async await threading is that you may not be executing on the thread you started from.  Unity attempts to make this the case but it doesn't always work.  I would suggest you read up on that topic.  One way to quickly test is jam the value into a static variable and flip a static bool to true after the data is loaded, then do playerprefs work in an update call that is checking for the bool to be true.  That would guarantee it is on main thread.

Comment: I'm guessing that GetValueAsync is a function decorated with the async keyword, which means "continue running on a thread".  If you aren't familiar with that part of C# (it's actually pretty advanced and can be confusing) it is easy to get tangled in Unity.  Do the least work possible in continuations, and it will go smoother.

Comment: Ive just tried the test, but the program doesnt even want to set an integer as the value read from the database, still no errors. Yup, the GetValueAsync function is decorated with the async keyword.